# Add a number to SELECTED field names mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there an easy way to add a number "2" to a MySQL SELECT STATEMENT. I keep getting an error.

```
SELECT field_name AS '2' + field_name from table_data as tbl
left join another_table as ic on ic.id = tbl.provider " .
where pid = '3' and type = "secondary" order by date DESC limit 1
```

Comment: I don't understand... why don't you just write `2field_name`?

Comment: Do you mean concat with field or add to field ?

Comment: It is not as easy as 2field_name since I want to add a "2" for each field name

Comment: SELECT * AS "2" + * ? I know is not correct

Comment: what is datatype of fieldname ?

Comment: datatype is string names

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT field_name + 2 
FROM table_data AS tbl
LEFT JOIN another_table AS ic ON ic.id = tbl.provider 
WHERE pid = '3' AND TYPE = "secondary" 
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this It is simple like

```
SELECT `field_name`+2
FROM table_data AS tbl
LEFT JOIN another_table AS ic ON ic.id = tbl.provider " . 
WHERE pid = '3'
  AND TYPE = "secondary"
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

```
SELECT field_name + 2 FROM table_data AS tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN another_table AS ic ON ic.id = tbl.provider 
WHERE pid = '3' AND type = "secondary" 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The `MySQL AS keyword` is used to specify an alternate name (or alias) to use when referring to either `a table or a column (field) in a table`.
[Refer here for more details](http://www.tutorialarena.com/mysql/mysql-as-keyword.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve.

The `AS` keyword identifies the column name assigned to the expression in the resultset. This has to be a valid identifier, can't be an expression.

If you want to prepend a literal `'2'` to the value stored in `field_name` column of each row, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('2',field_name) AS `2field_name`
```

But again, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

The metadata for the resultset, including the identifiers (names) assigned to the columns in the resultset is set at the time the statement is prepared. The name of the column in the resultset is the SAME for each and every row. That's why it has to be an identifier; it can't vary from row to row. (Much like the column name in a table doesn't change from row to row; it's specified at the time the table is created. The columns in the resultset are specified at the time the resultset is specified; the values stored/returned in a table/resultset doesn't affect the column name.)

Comment: Basically the field names to be displayed later were named 2field_x, 2_field_y... I would like to see if I can add the number during the SELECT portion

Comment: @user2031297: you can use an expression in the select list; you can use the value stored in the `field_name` column of the table in any expression you want. But the query is returning a single column, and the name of the column returned must be specified as a valid identifier. The name of the returned column is fixed at the time the SQL statement is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody!! What I ended up doing is to not try to rename the field names at the SELECT DB part. I let the query run and after that I did a foreach

```
 foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    unset ($result[$k]);

    $new_key = "2" . $k;

    $result[$new_key] = $v;
   }
```